# Use browser-mob proxy with eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob-proxy

I am using Eclipse to develop a test scenario with selenium java and want to capture the har using browser-mob proxy.

However the import commands are throwing this error

**Error**

> The import net.lightbody cannot be resolved

**code**

```
import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxy;
import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer;
```

Comment: Should i add any jar to the eclipse project?

Comment: i have downloaded the zip from http://bmp.lightbody.net/ (browsermob-proxy-2.1.4-bin.zip) and have referenced the jar browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar after doing this the error (imort cannot be resolved) seems to not appear anymore.